# Dot operator in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I thought I've known the [String Operator](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) `.` well enough until I was asked a question about it today. The question looks quite simple:

```
echo 100...100;
```

At the first glance I thought it would make a syntax error. But when I ran the code and saw the result I was totally confused. The result is

```
1000.1
```

So I wonder how could this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: @Gordon,typo error fixed ,sorry

Comment: imo this shouldn't be close. it's a fair question for new users

Comment: @yes the closevotes stemmed from before the OP fixing the typo that made the question bogus. And yes, it shouldnt be closed after fixing anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read it like this:

```
(100.) . (.100)
```

Thus it concats `100` and `0.1`.

Comment: No, not actually, there is no `0` in the middle, it comes from the `.1 == 0.1`.

Comment: Then `echo 100..100` should be the same result cuz it equals `(100).(.100)`?But it's not.

Comment: SpawnCxy: Apparently `100.` will be cast to string only if string follows after `.`. Otherwise it will be resolved as `100.0`

Comment: @Spawn nope. using `100..100` is ambigious. It could mean `100. .100` (=> Fatal) or `100 . .100` (=> 1000.1) or `100. . 100` (=> 100100). `100...100` not ambiguous. When the parser sees `100..100` it has to decide between these three and apparently choses the Fatal.

Comment: @Gordon,it seems PHP parses this as your first one (syntax error).Maybe because decimal point operator has higher priority than concatenation operator.

Comment: @Spawn likely. if you want to know the nitty gritty details, have a look at the source code.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you meant

```
echo 100...100;
```

The reason for this is the beauty of PHP. :)
This statement is understood as

```
100. . .100
```

which is equivalent to

```
100.0 . 0.1
```

<=>

```
'100' . '0.1'
```

<=>

```
'1000.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read it as `echo 100 . 0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that only works without the quotes:

```
echo "100...100";   100...100  << with quotes the . is just a char

echo 100 . 100;     100100     << two concatenated strings "100"

echo 100.100;       100.1      << 100.100 is just a number

echo 100...100;     1000.1     << what you asked

echo 100. . .100;   1000.1     << what PHP actually interprets
```